# Can a finite group have its third cohomology determined by a quotient group?

Tags: finite-groups, group-cohomology

Does there exist a finite group $G$ satisfying either of the following?

- $G$ admits a non-trivial, proper, central subgroup $A$ such that every (normalized) 3-cocycle of $G$ is cohomologous to a (normalized) 3-cocycle of $G/A$ (viewed as a 3-cocycle of $G$ via the canonical projection).  Equivalently, the canonical projection induces a surjection $H^3(G/A,U(1))\to H^3(G,U(1))$.
- There exists $1\neq \alpha\in\operatorname{Out}(G)$ such that $\alpha$ acts trivially on $H^3(G,U(1))$.

It would be particularly nice to know if there are examples satisfying all combinations (first but not the second; second but not the first; both).

The conditions are related in the sense that if the first condition holds for some $A$ and there exists a group homomorphism $\phi\colon G\to A$ such that $g\mapsto \phi(g)g$ defines a non-trivial outer automorphism of $G$, then this automorphism acts trivially on the cocycles $Z^3(G/A,U(1))$, and so must act trivially on $H^3(G,U(1))$.

The answer to this question turns out to be related to the existence of "unusual" tensor (but not necessarily braided)  auto-equivalences of $\operatorname{Rep}(D^\omega(G))$, the category of finite dimensional representations of a twisted group double, *which are independent of the cohomology class of $\omega$*.  Exactly what I mean by "unusual" is left intentionally vague, but examples of the first condition strike me as the most unusual and therefore most interesting.

I feel like the second condition is sure to be satisfied by a relatively easy example while the first must either have a known example or an obvious reason it must fail, but examples or disproofs have escaped me.

I'll note that I posted a [similar, but more restrictive, question with respect to the cocycle groups $Z^3(G,U(1))$ and $Z^3(G/A,U(1))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649560/can-a-group-have-the-same-3-cocycles-as-one-of-its-quotients) on Math.SE that did not receive an answer.  A positive answer to that question automatically provides an example of the first condition here.